# Direct BIRT Report logs to log4j

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j, birt

I have a spring mvc 3.0 webapp and am I am trying to follow the instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Logging to redirect the birt report logs to log4j but am having some troubles understanding how to do it.

Step one to create the class is fine.

Step two to create configuration file "logging.properties" and specify above handler as handers: handlers=test.Log4jHandler

What exactly should be the content of logging.properties? An example would be great.

Step three I don't really understand either. I assume that means put the file in the classpath... but then how do I set the position by system property?

If anyone can help with a good example that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our application (not using spring), we do it like this:

Content of the file c:\reporting\conf\birt\birt-log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, file
# Set to DEBUG to see a lot more messages from BIRT

log4j.logger.org.eclipse=INFO, engine
log4j.additivity.org.eclipse=false

log4j.logger.org.eclipse.birt=INFO, engine
log4j.additivity.org.eclipse.birt=false

log4j.logger.org.eclipse.birt.data=WARN, engine
log4j.additivity.org.eclipse.birt.data

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/reporting/log/birt/birt.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}] %-5p [%t] J:%X{jobId} - (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.engine=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.engine.File=C:/reporting/log/birt/engine.log
log4j.appender.engine.MaxFileSize=2000KB
log4j.appender.engine.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.engine.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.engine.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}] %-5p [%t] J:%X{jobId} - %c - %m%n
```

And when starting the application, we set a SystemProperty like this:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/reporting/conf/birt/birt-log4j.properties
```

And inside the application, we are using org.yajul.log.JuliToLog4JService (see http://yajul.sourceforge.net/) and set it up like this:

```
private JuliToLog4JService logHelper;


/**
 * Initialize the BIRT and logging libraries.
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
private void initLogging() throws Exception {
    logHelper = new JuliToLog4JService();
    logHelper.start();
}


private void initBIRT() throws ConfigurationError {

    String birtFontDirs = System.getProperty("birt.font.dirs");
    fontPath = birtFontDirs.split(File.pathSeparator);
    // Check that the report directory exists
    File f = new File(reportDir);
    boolean dirOk = false;
    dirOk = (f.isDirectory());
    if (!dirOk) {
        log.fatal("Specified report directory " + String.valueOf(reportDir)
                + " is not a directory or not accessible!");
        throw new ConfigurationError("Invalid report directory "
                + String.valueOf(reportDir));
    }
    log.info("Creating BIRT EngineConfig...");
    engineConfig = new EngineConfig();

    engineConfig.setLogger(java.util.logging.Logger
            .getLogger("org.eclipse.BIRTengine"));

    dbUrl = System.getProperty("lisa.birt.db.url");
    log.info("DB URL=" + dbUrl);

    try {
        log.info("Platform startup...");
        Platform.startup(engineConfig);
        log.info("Creating report engine factory...");
        factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);

        log.info("Creating report engine...");
        engine = factory.createReportEngine(engineConfig);
        engine.setLogger(engineConfig.getLogger());
        // reportEngine.changeLogLevel(Level.parse(logLevel));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.fatal("Error during BIRT startup!", e);
        throw new ConfigurationError("Error during BIRT platform startup");
    }
    log.info("BIRT EngineManager initialization completed.");
}

/**
 * Shut down the engine manager. Before destroying the BIRT report engine,
 * interrupt the generator threads.
 */
public void shutdownBIRT() {
    // Interrupt the still running threads
    log.info("Shutting down BIRT engine...");

    // destroy the engine
    if (engine != null) {
        try {
            log.info("Destroying BIRT ReportEngine...");
            engine.destroy();
            engine = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Error calling reportEngine.destroy:", e);
        }
    }
    // shut down BIRT OSGI platform
    try {
        log.info("Shutting down BIRT OSGI platform...");
        Platform.shutdown(); // FIMXE This seems to hang.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Error calling Platform.shutdown:", e);
    }
    log.info("BIRT EngineManager shutdown completed.");
}

/**
 * Uninitialize the BIRT and logging libraries.
 */
private void uninitialize() {
    shutdownBIRT();
    try {
        logHelper.stop();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        try {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } catch (Throwable t1) {
            ; // ignore if we cannot log the error
        }
    }
}
```

As a nice side-effect, you can use MDC with log4j. E.g. our application is using BIRT multi-threaded, and log4j can automatically add a meaningful identifier for the thread to the log line.

For the IDE, we aren't using log4j. In order to direct BIRT's log messages to a not-so-deeply-nested log file, we just start the IDE like this (in Windows):

```
start /D%~dp0birt %BIRT_EXE% -clean -vmargs -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%~dp0logging.properties
```

with a file logging.properties like this:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler

.level= INFO

org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.level = FINE

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ../log/birt-designer.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 5000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I'll keep this in mind if I cannot get the instructions posted in my original post to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with your own custom java.util.logging Handler you need to create logger with "org.eclipse.birt.report"

```
...    
engineConfig.setLogger(java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.birt.report"));
...
```